# Stripping ints from a string in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column like this:

```
      Age
15-20 years old
20-25 years old
```

**I want this as output:**

```
Age_Min   Age_Max
  15         20
  20         25
```

I am trying to use `str.strip()` but no success so far.

I tried `d[['Age_Min','Age_Max']]=d['Age'].str.split('-',expand=True)`

and the result is almost there.  Is there a way to get only the integers and remove the string?

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
In [858]: out = df['Age'].str.split('-', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Age_Min', 1: 'Age_Max'})
    
In [860]: out['Age_Max'] = out['Age_Max'].str.split().str[0]

In [861]: out
Out[861]: 
  Age_Min Age_Max
0      15      20
1      20      25
```

**OR using `regex`:**

```
In [870]: out = df['Age'].str.extract("(\d*\-?\d+)")[0].str.split('-', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Age_Min', 1: 'Age_Max'})

In [871]: out
Out[871]: 
  Age_Min Age_Max
0      15      20
1      20      25
```